# SecurityException using RegistryKey.OpenSubKey()

Tags: c#, .net

This line works:

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    baseKeyName + subKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

While these lines produce a `SecurityException - Requested registry access is not allowed on the OpenSubKey` line:

```
RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
   RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
RegistryKey registryKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(
   baseKeyName + subKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

On the same Win7 machine.

I'm doing it this way because in the 'real' code there is a conditional that will use the the Registry64 RegistryView on 64 bit machines.

Anyone got any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the LocalMachine registry area is not allowed unless the application is running elevated as an administrator.

Comment: It was running at administrator level.

Comment: After further testing it appears that you can only use the RegistryView approach on a 64 bit machine ie where there is both 32 and 64 bit registry views. If you use it in a 32 bit Win7 as I was you get a security exception.